# 07 Suzuki Boulevard S40 leaking gas

Tags: motorcycle, carburetor, leak

My Suzuki S40/LS650 isn't starting, or starts but wont idle. I also noticed that it's dripping fuel after I try to start it. I have an idea that it's the carburetor and would appreciate any suggestions. I'm going to try to remove/disassemble/clean and reinstall the carburetor myself, and wonder if there is something I should be looking for, or something that needs to be replaced.  Many thanks

Comment: Float stuck open from gummed up or dirty carb. Is there a tutorial on the Suzuki forums about that disassembling that carb? Maybe check for one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like the carburetor, float, and/or float valve may be dirty.

**NOTE: A service manual will be extremely helpful as you go thru this process.**

There is no reason to take this carburetor apart and not rebuild it. So, get a carburetor rebuild kit, which contains the necessary seals/gaskets and other items needing replaced.

After disassembly, all of the main parts need to be cleaned with carburetor cleaner. Look for blocked passages and for areas where there is/was residue to ensure it is all cleaned out.

There is some good information over at [SuzukiSavage.com](http://suzukisavage.com/home/) for many maintenance topics for LS650, S40 bikes. There are also a few "how to" videos on YouTube.

Comment: Both suggestions are great. I looked at a couple of the YouTube videos and was going to use them.  I'll also get the rebuild kit. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You are welcome. Additional advice, when you back out the set screws, record the number of turns to remove them. Then when you put them back in, you can get very close to the original set point. Also, if this answered your question, please accept it by using the check mark under the voting buttons on the left. This will let searchers know there is an answer to this question.